# Тинейджер или тинэйджер?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: тинейджер или тинэйджер?

Answer (score 3):

*Тин**е**йджер* - по правилам практической транскрипции (teenager): *после согласной* английская буква **a** с чтением  [eɪ] передаётся как **-ей-**; в начале же слова - как **эй-**. См. в википедии статью "Англо-русская практическая транскрипция".

Answer (score 1):

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A0%D1%91%D0%A0%D0%85%D0%A0%C2%B5%D0%A0%E2%84%96%D0%A0%D2%91%D0%A0%C2%B6%D0%A0%C2%B5%D0%A1%D0%82&all=x)

ТИНЕЙДЖЕР [нэ], -а; м. [англ. teenager - подросток] Подросток, молодой человек 14 - 17 лет. <Тинейджерный; тинейджерский, -ая, -ое. Т. возраст. Т-ие проблемы.